# What does '>' mean when used as a JQuery selector?

Tags: jquery

Apologies if this is a stupid question but it is quite hard to find using a search engine, but what does the '>' operator mean when used as a selector?

E.g.

```
$('div.form-input > label')....
```

Comment: Child selector: http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: Just as a note, this syntax also works inside of CSS. A lot of jQuery selectors are based off of CSS selectors.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's parent > child - select all elements matching the second selector that are children of elements matching the first selector. For example:

```
div.myclass > p.yourclass
```

will select all p's of yourclass that are inside a div of myclass.

Answer (score 5):

The same as in CSS, a label directly inside a div with class `form-input`

```
$('div.form-input label') // label can be anywhere inside the div

$('div.form-input > label') // label must be directly inside the div (at top level)
```

Comment: for 58k rep answer it should be more precise than "directly inside"

Answer (score 4):

```
jQuery('parent > child')
```

Description: Selects all direct child elements specified by "child" of elements specified by "parent".

http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 3):

It is same with css selector, select for the direct child.

Answer (score 3):

It selects the child of a div with class "form-input" that is a label.  You can read more about child selector here http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Answer (score 3):

It's the `child` selector. See more [here](http://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/).

Answer (score 1):

`div.form-input > label` selector will match the direct `label` descendant of the `div.form-input`